# Trouble with Distortion on UV Map of CSS Virginia

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm having trouble with some distortion on my unwraps on the upper hull of the [CSS Virginia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_Virginia).

Initially, I tried using top down orthographic unwraps of the mesh, but in those attempts (one meant for a tiling texture, the second for more traditional texturing) there is some obvious distortion (especially near the top of the hull.

I've also used unwraps with seams, but they don't seem to make any difference. I'm quite stuck as to how to resolve that distortion.

[image: unwrap 1]
[image: uvs]

[image: unwrap 2]
[image: uvs]

Comment: Could you upload your .blend file

Comment: how exactly do you want to see the texture on the model?

Comment: Have you tried to increase the subdivisions of the Subsurf Modifier?

Comment: @: Igor Tatarnikov: Yes I can, hopefully this comment won't close before I finish because I accidentally hit ENTER. @: Denis: I'm still trying to either use a single 'plate' texture and use a non 0-1 space or tile the texture. If not, I'll end up plating the hull by hand in 0-1 space. @Gonzou: This asset will end up on a mobile game and this hull doubles as a collider (and generally more geo = more computation time) so I'm trying not to add any more geo than necessary, but it may be the only solution.

Comment: Here is a cleaned file, let me know if you want an earlier version on this (I used "split non planar faces" on this one) [hull file](http://rg.to/file/13d9f6433ecfbeea0c2775945d52ff41/cssvirginia_for_upload.blend.html)

Answer (score 5):

I think you should try to increase the level of *subdivisions* of the ***Subsurf Modifier***.
[image]

It may also be the matter of how you've unwrapped your mesh. I'll suggest you the way how to do it.
Add an edge as pictured below, select it and mark a seam (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>-->*Mark Seam*)
[image]

Unwrap the mesh using ***Follow Active Quads*** method. Select the whole mesh (<kbd>A</kbd>), then press <kbd>U</kbd>-->*Follow Active Quads*-->*Lenght Average*-->*OK*.
[image]

The result of the unwrapping (after you scale the UV island) may be something like this.
[image]

Now you have quite even distribution of the texture and there is no distortion.
[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you for the very thorough instructions. I tried it on a few of my models, but unfortunately they all ended up looking fairly insane (I'm guessing either the geometry is too 'complex' or that the cut-outs for the ports are messing things up. I'll give the extra geometry and try and see how it goes. Thank you very much. [Texture](http://i62.tinypic.com/ilc9qu.jpg) [UVs](http://i61.tinypic.com/15g9le9.jpg)